# npm freezes on "idealTree:31645: sill idealTree buildDeps" when I'm trying to install packages

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I'm stuck with this error "idealTree:31645: sill idealTree buildDeps" when I'm trying to install npm packages. A couple of days ago I connected to mobile hotspot and after I reconnected to my WiFi network I got the error and I  can't install any packages. I guess its probably because of the settings.

I delete my Node and I reinstalled, I removed the node-modules and install it again but same issue.
I googled it and I applied all suggestions, but nothing works.

Any ideas?